# Flash as3 smooth threshold

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm building a flash app that pulls images from flickr and removes the white background
I'm dong this using threshold and i get a really ragged outcome
is there any way to get a better and smoother color key?
thanks
`photoNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (photos.length));`

```
    loader.load(new URLRequest(photos[photoNumber].path));
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,draw);
    trace ( "trying to load photo " + photoNumber );

    function draw(e:Event) {

    trace ("show photo " + photoNumber)

var W:int=e.target.content.width;
var H:int=e.target.content.height;

bitmapdata=new BitmapData(W,H);
bitmap=new Bitmap(bitmapdata);
bitmapdata.draw(e.target.content);

    var threshold:uint =  0xF9F8F800;
    var color:uint = 0x00000000;
    var maskColor:uint = 0x00FF0000;

bitmapdata.threshold(bitmapdata,new Rectangle(0,0,W,H),new Point(0,0),">", threshold, color, maskColor, true);

    bitmap.smoothing = true;
    //bitmap.scaleX = bitmap.scaleY = 0.99; // <----
    imgHolder.addChild(bitmap);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Your mask and thresholds are not correct. I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
var threshold:uint =  0x00F9F8F8;
var maskColor:uint = 0x00FFFFFF;
```

The alpha is the first two hex chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to remove white pixels you can compare the image with a white bitmap in the same size and change the matching pixels (see: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#compare%28%29).